# Transfer a date from a input box or form to a record field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Good Day all,

I have a form setup for data entry; ID, C_Date, Amount....etc. Is it possible to have an input box popup before data entry, the user enters a Date and the date is passed onto C_Date so the user doesn't need to reenter the date every time just for that batch of records.

Much Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is but you will have to use some VBA.

Personally I would not use a popup. I would use an unbound text box on the form's header, then script the OnCurrent event to copy that value to your C_Date field if C_Date is null. That way you don't have to worry about storing the value and you also allow your users to see/change it at will.